# jsGrid LoadData - done() is not called after ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jsgrid

Consider the following code sample from my grid controller:

```
    loadData: function (filter) {
        var data = $.Deferred(); // This line is hit.
        var rsp = null;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json: charset=utf-8',
            url: loadRoute,
            data: filter,
            dataType: 'JSON'
        }).done(function (response)
        {
            // This function is never invoked.
            debugger;
            rsp = response;
            data.resolve(response);
        });
        return data.promise();
    },
```

When I debug this code, a breakpoint set on the first line of `loadData` is successfully hit; however, the `debugger` statement inside `done` is never hit. I can't see any obvious reason why.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

As far as I can tell this method must return a promise, which I am doing. Further, I have to resolve the data returned from the AJAX call to unpack it, which I am also doing (provided I can hit `done`).

FWIW, the server side code is invoked (`loadUrl`) and returns without error. But because I can't get into `done`, I can't inspect the data.

Comment: If the .done callback is not invoked, it may likely be that the Ajax request is somehow failing (not necessarily related to the request itself though). Did you try to add an `error` callback and check if, somehow, it's going in there? If you're 100% confident that the .done callback is not being executed than there **must** be something related to the ajax section.

Comment: add this inside your `done()` callback: `console.log(response)` before `debugger`

Comment: @briosheje Thank you, that helped. Turns out, I'm getting back a full view, even though my ASP.NET MVC controller method is set up to return a `JsonResult`. Looks like I have a different problem to solve. Can you put your comment as an answer so I can give you appropriate credit?

Comment: @MikeHofer : Just try to solve the issue, I can't really formulate any "proper" response to the problem, since mine is only a guess (I could expect what the problematic could be, but I'm likely unable to tell exactly where the issue is). I would be glad already if you can find a starting point for your current issue, that's it ;)

Comment: @briosheje Heh. I meant to copy your first comment (re: "if the .done callback is not invoked...") into an answer. I know you can't solve the other issue with the limited info available. I just want to give you appropriate credit for solving the issue in this post.